# How to use a @foreach loop inside laravel Form::select element

Tags: laravel-5

```
<select>
 @foreach($users as $user)
<option>{{$user->Cus_Code}} - {{$user->Cus_Name}}</option>
@endforeach
</select>
```

I have the above working code.
What I need is to use it with a laravel form::select element.

Something like this....

```
{!!Form::select('aaa',null,array({{$user->Cus_Code}} - {{$user->Cus_Name}})) !!}
```

Is it possible with laravel 5???

Answer (score 1):

In your controller

```
foreach($users as $user){
  $users_array[$user->id] = $user->Cus_Code . " - " . $user->Cus_Name
}
```

and then you can pass `$users_array` to the view.

In your view

```
{!!Form::select('aaa', null, $users_array) !!}
```